# Download all files from all artifacts (artifact names) except from one in AzureDevOps YAML pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a pipeline with with some stages like

```
Build -> Dev -> Test -> Prod
```

The build stage generate some nugets for different parts of the system. As this happen in different jobs, a couple of artifact names is published like:

```
server\server.nupkg
client\client.nupkg
auth\auth.nupkg
```

Those are then consumed in the following stages that dowload, apply variable substitution to some configs and publish a new nuget configured to an environment as a drop.

For example the test stage has one job that transform the config in the needed nuget and publish that as an pipeline artifact. So at that point the artifacts for the hole pipeline looks like:

```
server\server.nupkg
client\client.nupkg
auth\auth.nupkg
Test
  server.nupkg
  client.nupkg
  auth.nupkg
```

When it comes to the prod stage i want to download all *.nupkg from all artifact names **except** from the **Test** artifact name.

I've tried to use an exclude patterns in the 'DownloadPipelineArtifact' task like this but no success:

```
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  displayName: Download nugets
  inputs:
    buildType: 'current'
    itemPattern: |
      '*/*.nupkg'
      '!Test'
      '!Test/*.nupkg'
    targetPath: '$(MyDirectory)/nugets'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If `server`, `client`, `auth` and `Test` are different artifacts then you should be able to either download the first three separately or do it in a single task invocation by using "exclude" [file matching pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns) with first segment being the artifact name. See [Publish and download artifacts in Azure Pipelines | Multiple artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifactsk#multiple-artifacts).

Example #1, download artifacts separately:

```yaml
- download: current
  artifact: server

- download: current
  artifact: client

- download: current
  artifact: auth
```

---

Although, based on the current docs, the following example is supposed to work, it doesn't. It looks like the docs are incorrect. See this issue for details:

- https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/3416

Example #2, download artifacts using file matching patterns:~~

*Note double asterisk for recursive wildcard and the absence of the quotes that would be included literally in the multiline YAML string otherwise.*

```yaml
- download: current
  patterns: |
    **/*.nupkg
    !Test/**
```

Comment: Hi @beatcracker, thanks for you reply. I've tried the Example #2 wit no success.
Seems that the exclude is applied to the files inside the artifact name. But not to the artifact name itself.
So the files are still downloaded.

Comment: @Diego, curious, I'll try to setup a test pipeline to validate this and get back you.

Comment: @Diego I've run some tests and it doesn't work indeed. I've raised an issue in the agent repo, since this contradicts documentation: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/3416

Comment: @Diego Looks like the docs are wrong and the second example is not supposed to work. I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Hi @beatcracker thanks a lot for your help and the updates!
In the example above I have 3 artifacts but in one of our projects we have 10+ so I was trying to avoid writing a download statement separately and depending of the explicit names. I guess is give a much longer YAML but it more declarative perhaps.

Comment: @Diego Yeah, I totally get it. What I would do in this case is try to put `Test` artifacts into the subfolder: `Test\test\*.nuget`. This way patterns should work. This might be easier to support then multi-artifact download.

Comment: Thanks again! Yes, it is an option! The downside as I understand it, is that it is limited for artifacts coming from the same job. In my case I've each artifact coming from a different job so they can be build in parallel.